# Run a custom script extension from Visual Studio ARM Template

Tags: powershell, azure, visual-studio-2015, azure-rm-template

I have a project in Visual Studio for my ARM templates. One of the templates is for a VM and I am deploying a Custom Script Extension for the VM as well.
The script is in a .ps1 file that is part of the project (in the projects, I have a scripts folder). The whole project, including the script is under TFS for versioning.

How do I point the template to use the .ps1 file in my VS Project? 
At the moment, I am simply uploading the file to a storage and pointing the template there, i.e:

```
           "settings": {
          "fileUris": [ "https://mystorageaccount.blob.core.windows.net/scripts/myPowerShelScriptFile.ps1" ],
          "commandToExecute": "[variables('commandToExecute')]"
        },
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well, according to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/virtual-machines-windows-extensions-customscript#troubleshoot-and-support), you just need to do:

```
powershell "powershell.exe . . . -File './myPowerShelScriptFile.ps1'"
```

edit: arm templates don't work like that, you don't upload a file, you upload a template and that file get's downloaded only by the resource that is actually working with the file.

Comment: I think this applies to the commandToExecute, what I am struggling with is the fileUris. Yes, I understand the file is downloaded to the VM and executed, it's where it is downloaded from that I need to set. I want it to be from my VS project rather than the storage account

Comment: so I don't understand the problem, convert that into a parameter or a variable and make vs upload your script there

Comment: Thought there was a more elegant way like pointing it to the local file rather than something public